# Un-known web server “…scontent-ord1-1xxx”

Tags: macos, google-chrome, html, malware

I am running El Capitan on my macbook. After downloading some software from Download.com, it installed some garbage (ebay search bar etc.) I removed all the added downloads however I am noticing my web browsers loading slowly and un-reliably. I've also noticed some weird addresses showing up in the status bar. Most which are normal urls but on in particular I can find no information about on Google. The url contains "scontent-ord1-1". Any ideas what this is?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net, [VirusTotal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirusTotal), a site now owned by Google that allows one to upload files to be scanned by multiple antivirus programs, shows information on that [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) at:

[scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net](https://www.virustotal.com/en/domain/scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/information/)

The IP address belonging to that FQDN is [31.13.74.7](https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html?searchtext=31.13.74.7#resultsAnchor), which is an IP address assigned to Facebook.